# e1000e: probe failed with error -2

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I was wondering if someone could help me with an odd problem...

I have a Lenovo ThinkCentre M92P Desktop PC, which has an Intel Onboard LAN Card that doesn't want to initialize and I don't know what the hell is the problem with it...

I'll post some of my configs:

lspci:

```
infosky [~] # lspci |grep Etherne
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
```

lshw:

```
infosky [~] # lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff memory:f7e35000-f7e35fff ioport:f080(size=32)
```

dmesg:

```
infosky [~] # dmesg |grep e1000
[    0.678546] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    0.680549] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.688720] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.951961] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2
```

uname -a:

```
Linux infosky 5.4.0-59-generic #65-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 10 12:01:51 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ubuntu version:

```
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
```

In BIOS, the Oboard LAN is enabled and LAN Booting is Disabled.

All updates are already performed.
System up-to-date. LAN Card not recognized by driver, I assume.
Something has to do with that "probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2" which I don't know what it means.

I was thinking about installing Intel's drivers from their website but this seems a little too much to do.
The drivers should be naturally integrated in the kernel.
If I install manual drivers, then this means that everytime I get a kernel update I must manually reinstall drivers ? This sucks...

If anyone can lend a helping hand, it would be very appreciated... :-)

Thanks !

Comment: This older but maybe relevant Ubuntu forum post may help you https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2343294

Comment: Thank you, but mine is Error -2... and I already updated the BIOS. Nothing happened.

Comment: Can you try this in a terminal: `sudo rmmod e1000e` then `sudo modprobe e1000e`. If the network starts up properly after that, then an edit will need to be made to `/etc/rc.local`. Otherwise, you'll likely need to go the route of installing drivers from Intel.

Comment: I was reading around the internets and https://www.whtop.com/blog/e1000e-probe-failed-with-error-2/ stated that they disabled the WOL in BIOS, but then they ended up performing a hard power reset of the system.  Hard power reset is where you pull all power to the host, if a laptop you pull the battery as well.  With no power, press the power button a few times, then plug the power back in and power back on.  I would try the power reset first.

Comment: If you boot with the cable detached, can you successfully `sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep e100` If you then reinsert the cable, does the ethernet work as expected? Is this a dual-boot with Windows?

Comment: infosky [~] # rmmod e1000e
infosky [~] # modprobe e1000e
infosky [~] # dmesg |grep e1000
[74829.864697] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[74829.864699] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[74829.865025] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[74831.107869] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2

The result is the same.
I already left the system without a single miliAmp of power (except battery), still no luck. What the hell does "-2" mean ? Is there a method to further debug this ?

Comment: I don't think anyone except for Developers (either Canonical or Intel) will know what the error -2 means.  Chili555 helped someone here https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2404122.html  troubleshoot one.  You might actually be experiencing a hardware failure.  Also, try what @chili555 suggested above about booting the system without the network cable attached.

Comment: That interface does not have a cable attached....

Comment: I regret that the only possibility that I suspect is a defective device. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the only difference is that I had a code `-5`

`e1000e: probe failed with error -5`

I have Asrock B360 with Gigabit intel ethernet adapter (I219-V). BIOS update - did not help at all.
So what I did: I reset BIOS, removed motherboard battery plug for a while then put it back - started the system and no way! `eth0` interface now is back!